# How to show the latest time and date from this JSON on google maps?

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I am building an app where i need track persons.I track them with their email ids.I need your help in showing a marker on Google Map. I need to show different users and their latest position. I am able to parse JSON but I am showing all the objects. I only want to show the latest position and email id.

Tracking.JSON

```
{
  "TrackingMobile": [
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.4248105",
      "longitude": "78.4577176",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 13:51:15"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.44664",
      "longitude": "78.4588982",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 14:31:34"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.4466195",
      "longitude": "78.4588767",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 14:32:20"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.4456307",
      "longitude": "78.4608069",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 14:32:21"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.4465473",
      "longitude": "78.4588212",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 14:33:14"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.44655605",
      "longitude": "78.45901514",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 14:33:21"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.44659697",
      "longitude": "78.45909601",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 14:33:22"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.4247139",
      "longitude": "78.4575489",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 14:44:46"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.4247947",
      "longitude": "78.457708",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 14:45:14"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "kalam@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.4248069",
      "longitude": "78.4576888",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 15:10:09"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.4248051",
      "longitude": "78.4577212",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 13:44:30"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.4248092",
      "longitude": "78.4577201",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 13:45:15"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.4248031",
      "longitude": "78.4577285",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 13:46:00"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.4248068",
      "longitude": "78.457734",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 13:46:45"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.424788",
      "longitude": "78.4577683",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 13:48:15"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.4248057",
      "longitude": "78.4577601",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 13:49:00"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.4248039",
      "longitude": "78.4577431",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 13:49:45"
    },
    {
      "emailid": "srikanth8605@gmail.com",
      "latitude": "17.424805",
      "longitude": "78.4577142",
      "dated": "2016/05/04 13:50:30"
    },
    {
      "end": "end"
    }
  ]
}
```

Class to Parse JSON.

```
public class ACTNearByPlaces extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    EditText etLng;
    EditText etLat;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static final String url = "http://www.ezomart.16mb.com/tracking.json";
    private static String TAG = "SRI";
    private int length;
    ArrayList<String> emailArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> dateArr = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actnear_by_places);





        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                hidePDialog();

                try {

                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("TrackingMobile");

                        for(int i = 0;i<array.length();i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject localJSONObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            String latitude = localJSONObject.getString("latitude");
                            String longitude = localJSONObject.getString("longitude");
                            String email = localJSONObject.getString("emailid");
                            String time = localJSONObject.getString("dated");


                            emailArr.add(email);
                            Collections.sort(emailArr);
                            dateArr.add(time);
                            Collections.sort(dateArr, Collections.reverseOrder());


                            Log.d(TAG, dateArr.toString());



                            Double doub_latitude = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                            Double doub_longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude);


                            // Creating LinkedHashSet
                            LinkedHashSet<String> lhs = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

                         /* Adding ArrayList elements to the LinkedHashSet
                          * in order to remove the duplicate elements and
                          * to preserve the insertion order.
                          */
                            lhs.addAll(emailArr);

                            // Removing ArrayList elements
                            emailArr.clear();

                            // Adding LinkedHashSet elements to the ArrayList
                            emailArr.addAll(lhs);

                            Log.d(TAG, emailArr.toString());


                            if (localJSONObject.getString("emailid").equalsIgnoreCase(email))
                            {
                                // create marker
                                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(doub_latitude, doub_longitude)).title(emailArr.get(0) + " " +dateArr.get(0));
                                googleMap.addMarker(marker);


                                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                                        new LatLng(doub_latitude, doub_longitude)).zoom(12).build();

                                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                            }

                        }
                    }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(ACTNearByPlaces.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(ACTNearByPlaces.this, "Please Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);


    }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move this part

```
if (localJSONObject.getString("emailid").equalsIgnoreCase(email)) {
     // create marker
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(doub_latitude, doub_longitude))
        .title(emailArr.get(0) + " " + dateArr.get(0));
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(doub_latitude, doub_longitude))
        .zoom(12)
        .build();

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```

out of the `for` loop, convert your string dates to `Date` objects using a `SimpleDateFormatter`, find the latest date in the array, get its index, and use it to retrieve the corresponding email.

However, it looks like your Json entries are already sorted, is that something that's guaranteed by Google Maps? If it is, you might just want to pick the last entry for a given email.

You could simply use a `HashMap<String, PositionRecord>`, using `emailid` as key, and a `PositionRecord` object that you define containing the other fields (`latitude`, `longitude`, `time`, and optionally even `email`). Whenever you parse a new entry, you call `hashMap.get(email)`, compare the entry's `time` with the one you just parsed, and replace the entry with `hashMap.put(email, new PositionRecord(latitude, longitude, time))` if the time you just parsed is more recent.

Finally, you just iterate over all entries in the hash map, and call the code I pasted above.